# I can not Install Ubuntu in my Samsung Galaxy Book Go

Tags: boot, system-installation, mount, uefi, arm

I got a Samsung Galaxy Book Go. I'm attempting to install Ubuntu, but the system startup screen installation  never loads. It just run the options when I boot it and when I select install doesn't run.

https://cdimage.ubuntu.com/focal/daily-live/current/

Processor   Snapdragon (TM) 7c Gen 2 @ 2.55 GHz   2.55 GHz
Installed RAM   4.00 GB (3.68 GB usable)
System type 64-bit operating system, ARM-based processor

Has anyone got a suggestion for how to fix this?

Comment: The *daily* images are for testing purposes, and can include features that are there (ie. from *-proposed*) to see if they work, so people can QA test them, and report any problems, so the *proposed* changes either move to *updates* or get dropped. As you're using a *daily* QA test image you're not using a *supported* or release product, your testing belongs on the ISO.QA tracker (http://iso.qa.ubuntu.com/) and any problems expressed on a bug tracker, not a support site such as this; https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs

Comment: The Galaxy Book Go's SnapDragon processor has almost zero Linux support outside of the operating system that the device ships with. People have tried and failed to install an alternative OS on that machine, which often results in having a Galaxy "Brick" instead.

Comment: *Focal* is the code name for Ubuntu 20.04, which was released almost three years ago. (The number before the dot in Ubuntu version numbers is the year, and the number after is the month; so Focal was released in April of 2020.) Although Focal has been updated since then, it's generally best to go with the latest OS version when dealing with new or unusual hardware. Ubuntu 22.04 ("Jammy") is the latest long-term support (LTS) version; Ubuntu 22.10 ("Kinetic") is even newer; and 23.04 ("Lunar") is approaching release. I can't promise better luck with any of these, but they may be worth trying.